# Locating matches with .csv files in python issue

Tags: python, csv

I have two .csv files in which I am attempting to find exact matches between the two.

First sheet is testnasdaq.csv and it contains:

```
Symbol
GOGO
WFTX
SYQD
B
```

Second sheet is mytickers.csv and it contains:

```
Symbol
GOGO
WFT
QD
S
```

I am using this code currently, but it is not giving the correct results and I can not seem to figure out why that is.

```
import csv
import requests

nasdaqDatabase = r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\testnasdaq.csv'

with open(nasdaqDatabase, "r") as f:
    nasdaq_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    nasdaq_symbols = set([row['Symbol'] for row in nasdaq_reader])
    with open(r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\mytickers.csv', 'r' ) as theFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(theFile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['Symbol'] in nasdaq_symbols:
                print(row['Symbol'], 'FOUND')
                newAddress = 'blank.com/' + row['Symbol'] + '.htm'
                print(newAddress)

        else:
                print(row['Symbol'], 'NOT FOUND')
                newAddress = 'blank.com/' + row['Symbol'] + '.htm'
                print(newAddress)
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
GOGO FOUND
blank.com/GOGO.htm
S NOT FOUND
blank.com/S.htm

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your if statement is comparing the `Symbol` with the `nasdaqDatabase` *filename*.  You should get the list/set of `Symbol`s from the `nasdaqDatabase` and compare it with `if row['Symbol'] in set_of_symbols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened the nasdaqDatabase as file but not read into a usable data structure. Try this:

```
import csv
import requests

nasdaqDatabase = r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\testnasdaq.csv'

with open(nasdaqDatabase, "r") as f:
    nasdaq_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    nasdaq_symbols = set([row['Symbol'] for row in nasdaq_reader])
    with open(r'C:\Users\Sterling\Desktop\StockProject\mytickers.csv', 'r' ) as theFile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(theFile)
        for row in reader:
            if row['Symbol'] in nasdaq_symbols:
                print(row['Symbol'], 'FOUND')
                newAddress = 'http://eoddata.com/stockquote/NASDAQ/' + row['Symbol'] + '.htm'
                print(newAddress)
            else:
                print(row['Symbol'], 'NOT FOUND')
                newAddress = 'http://eoddata.com/stockquote/NYSE/' + row['Symbol'] + '.htm'
                print(newAddress)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you a ton, worked perfectly. Now just so that I understand as to what I was doing wrong I was just forgetting to set up the row after opening the .csv? So the new line you added just creates a readable format of that column?

Comment: Sorry I've just realized that while that helps with matching it does not exactly match the words. It will still pick up similar words containing the original such as when searching for QD it will flag as a positive if SYQD is in the list that it is search from. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: the set created as nasdaq_symbols is set of strings, it will do exact match. If otherwise, show me your code or look for why it is not the case. The "in" operator in the if-statement works for both set and string. Are you making the nasdaq_symbols a string?

Comment: I have updated the OP with the updated code and spreadsheets displaying the issues. I haven't updated the in-between text on the OP though, but I can if more clarification is necessary.

Comment: your "else" does not match to "if" but to "for", move it one level more indent will work

Comment: HAHAHA wow I'm an idiot, just another sign I should take a break. Thank you so much for the continued help.